# HTML object vs. jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm a CoffeeScript and JavaScript novice.

Working here is with a blank Rails 3.2.8 app.
Here is the straight layout code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Editor</title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%= yield %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Could not be more simple, right? Now the view for the form:

```
<%= form_for(@note) do |f| %>
  <% if @note.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@note.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this note from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @note.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :body, class: 'tkh-editable' %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

While researching this topic I saw that many coders had problems with jQuery being loaded twice or in the wrong order.
Here are the non-comments in my application.js manifest file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require tkh_editor/tkh_editor
```

In the tkh_editor.js.coffee file, if I just put this code, it works just fine:

```
jQuery ->
  $(".tkh-editable").css("border","solid 5px red")
```

It adds a border around my textarea field with the class above.
I'm trying to create a plugin and I'm stuck at step 1.

Why is the following code not working?

```
jQuery.fn.extend
  tkhEditor: ->
    return @each ->
      this.css("border","solid 5px red")

jQuery ->
  $(".tkh-editable").tkhEditor()
```

The Chrome console gives me the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'css'

Please help and explain what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Actually, according to jQuery authoring guidelines http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring once done right, `this` inside your plugin code should be wrapped in jQuery already so you woudn't have to do what David suggest in his answer. Question is, how to reflect that in coffescript.

Comment: should post the resultant source code that is sent to page

Comment: @WTK It’s the `this` context inside the `.each` callback that needs to be wrapped.

Comment: @David Oh, you're right - my bad!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably just need to wrap `this` in jQuery. Try replacing:

```
this.css("border","solid 5px red")
```

with:

```
$(this).css("border","solid 5px red")
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks a lot. Makes total sense once you know the solution. ;-)

Comment: Exactly, this is true because JQuery Elements are basicly Wrapper objects with all the convenience functions like .css()

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `this`inside the `each` function, therefore `this` is not a jQuery object. Try this:

```
jQuery.fn.extend
  tkhEditor: ->
    return @each ->
      jQuery(this).css("border","solid 5px red")
```

If you want to use the `$` for jQuery, do this:

```
$ = jQuery
$.fn.extend
  tkhEditor: ->
    return @each ->
      $(this).css("border","solid 5px red")
```

Since coffeescript compiler produces an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression), and you cannot modify its arguments.

Comment: Thanks Serabe. David was a bit faster than you so I'll give him the answer.